# Using batch to get ID from "manage-bde -get"

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to automagically send a specific key to AD using a batch file.  I'm not able to use any other language unfortunately.  I'm using the results from:

```
manage-bde -protectors c: -get
```

and use the numerical password ID from that in this next code:

```
manage-bde -protectors -adbackup c: -id {numerical password ID}
```

Here's what I have so far (just trying to get the right key):

```
@echo off  
manage-bde -protectors c: -get  
echo+  
echo+  
echo+
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (' "manage-bde -protectors c: -get" ^| findstr ID') do set npi=%%b
echo+
echo+
echo My Numerical Password ID:
echo %npi%
echo+
pause
```

What I get is this:

> BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 6.1.7601
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Volume C: []
> All Key Protectors
>
> Numerical Password:
> ID: {DEDAF9BC-C42A-45A4-BB5D-609ED1898923} --I want this one--
> Password:
> 648712-106084-513103-486041-654894-310619-687401-654068
>
> TPM:
> ID: {DEDAF9BC-C42A-45A4-BB5D-609ED1898923}
>
>
> My Numerical Password ID:
> {DEDAF9BC-C42A-45A4-BB5D-609ED1898923}
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

I figured it would just grab the 1st "ID" that it came to but it keeps pointing to the 2nd one under TPM.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the help,

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `if not defined` before your `set`.  As you have your script above, `set` is being called twice because there are two lines that match `findstr "ID"`.  You're ending up with the second one because that is the last to be parsed.  `if not defined` captures the first one, then ignores every other.

On a minor note, there's no reason to capture `token=1,*` when all you want is the second token.

```
@echo off  
manage-bde -protectors c: -get  
echo+  
echo+  
echo+
set npi=
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('manage-bde -protectors c: -get ^| findstr "ID:"') do if not defined npi set "npi=%%a"
echo+
echo+
echo My Numerical Password ID:
echo %npi%
echo+
pause
```

Want to strip off the braces while you're at it?  Replace the `for` line with the following.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%a in ('manage-bde -protectors c: -get ^| findstr "ID:"') do if not defined npi set "npi=%%a"
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Nice job. I think I learned more about for statements from your help than in the past week of trying it on my own.  Thanks again for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

```
...
echo+
(set npi=)
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (
' "manage-bde -protectors c: -get" ^| findstr ID'
) do IF NOT DEFINED npi set npi=%%b
...
```

The extra SET forces npi to be UNSET if it has an existing value. Parenthesising the statement ensures that npi is NOT set to any trailing spaces on the line.

FOR /F processes every line of input, so `npi` is set first to the first value, then to the second. Adding the `IF NOT DEFINED` ensures the SET occurs if `npi` is er, not already defined hence it retains the FIRST value encountered.

Comment: btw - perfectly legitimate to judiciously break the FOR as shown - easier on the layout...

Comment: I like the way this is layed out.  Thanks for all the help.  I didn't expect such a quick response either.  :)

Comment: btw, I used the parenthesising idea.  Very well thought out.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old topic, but I found it yesterday and it was very helpful to me. I just wanted to add on to rojo's answer.

Working in Windows 10 - 1809, I have found that the order of IDs returned can vary by machine. If you want a script that just pulls the recovery key and sends it to AD, you can add a -type (or -t) RecoveryPassword to your manage-bde command.

rojo's updated code would look like this:

```
@echo off    
manage-bde -protectors c: -get -t RecoveryPassword
echo+  
echo+  
echo+
set npi=
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('manage-bde -protectors c: -get -t RecoveryPassword ^| findstr "ID:"') do set "npi=%%a"
echo+
echo+
echo My Numerical Password ID:
echo %npi%
echo+

manage-bde -protectors -adbackup c: -ID %npi%
pause
```